# Revoke reopen: correct procedure

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-reopen

Is there a possibility to revoke one's vote-to-reopen a question?

What is the procedure and the correct indications to follow?

Comment: Seems that is not possible at the moment (just tried it out over at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7982/35864), see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061.

Comment: Apparently I was using a wrong remembrance of mine: Close votes can be retracted, reopen votes not....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot revoke a vote to re-open. It's similar to casting a "Looks Good" vote on a post in the Low Quality Post review queue (say). Once it's cast, you can't take it back. However, you can retract close votes ([since Jun 2013](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/168244)).

Don't fret though, because you can cast a vote to close if the question gets re-opened, perhaps adding a comment to the post suggesting some support for your voting behaviour.

Comment: Accept your answer with enthusiasm. Than you very much.